# How to Make MessageKit Chat app without using fireBase in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift4, messagekit

I need to create **MessageKit** Chat app without using FireBase in Swift?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Message kit is not tied to Firebase at all you can use any database you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

1. Create a `MyMessagesViewController` and extends it from `MessagesViewController` MessageKit.

```swift
final class MyMessagesViewController: MessagesViewController {
   ...
}
```

2. Create your own `InputBarAccessoryView` extending from it, overriding `override func setup()` and set your subviews and layout up.

```swift
final class MyInputBarAccessoryView: InputBarAccessoryView {
   override func setup() {
      super.setup()
      // All your setup here
   }
}
```

And in `MyMessagesViewController` create the `messageInputBar`:

```swift
required init(...) {
   messageInputBar = MyInputBarAccessoryView()
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
   return true
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
   return messageInputBar
}
```

3. Create your own `MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout`, overriding `cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at:)` and create your own `CellSizeCalculator`, overriding `messageContainerSize(for:)` for returning a `CGSize` for each new message.

```swift
class MyMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout: MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout {

   private let sizeCalculator = MyMessageSizeCalculator()

   public override func cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellSizeCalculator {
      if case .custom = message.kind {
         return sizeCalculator
      }

      return super.cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at: indexPath)
   }
}
```

```swift
class MyMessageSizeCalculator: MessageSizeCalculator {
   override func messageContainerSize(for message: MessageType) -> CGSize {
      return size // Here you have to calculate your cell size based on message
   }
}
```

4. In `MyMessagesViewController` viewDidLoad method, create the `MessageCollectionView`, register nibs for cells and setup delegates.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   messageCollectionView = MessageCollectionView(
      frame: .zero,
      collectionViewLayout: MyCollectionViewFlowLayout()
   )

   // Common setups here

   // delegates
   messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
}
```

5. On `MessagesDataSourceDelegate` methods, implement `currentSender()` and returns your OWN currentSender just like you had to do when you used Firebase, but now you have to use a server sender ID or something like that. As you created your own custom cell, implement `customCell(for:, at:, in:)` and dequeue correctly the cell that you had registered.

```swift
func currentSender() -> SenderType {
   // You have to create some model that extends from SenderType and return here okay?
   return myClientSender
}

func customCell(
   for message: MessageType,
   at indexPath: IndexPath,
   in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   
   // dequeue correctly the cell based on message and indexPath
   return cell
}
```

It's the basic implementation for MessageKit custom cells. Obviously you would like to implement more things.

I hope it could help you :)